# operator in javascript with different type and value

Tags: javascript

- I am trying to understand a small piece of code
- I thought `!!`in javascript does the **not** operator two times

  ```
  var result = !!String("false");
  ```
- so I thought for the above code it will return as `false`
- but it returns `true`..and can you tell me why the type is `boolean`?

Comment: This was closed as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript/784946#784946 but I reopened it. The question isn't about what `!!` does, but why it returns a different result than he expected with this particular argument.

Comment: The really simple explanation, is that the string `"false"` is in fact true

Comment: Plus the fact that `!` always converts its argument to a boolean, so `!!<anything>` is not the same as `<anything>` unless `<anything>` is already a boolean.

Answer (score 5):

That is because,

1. `String("false")` will return `"false"`. A string.
2. `!"false"`  will be evaluated to `false`. 
                Since a non empty string will be considered as `true`
                when it coerces to `boolean`.
3. `!false`  will be evaluated to `true`.

Answer (score 2):

```
String("false")
```

Resolves to:

```
"false"
```

Which is a string that is non-empty, so

```
!"false"
```

Resolves to

```
false
```

And finally

```
!false
```

Resolves to

```
true
```